# Laravel 5.4 - Skip Model Mutator

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model mutator that adds a random string to the end of a slug.

```
public function setSlugAttribute($slug) {

  $slugNumber = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
  $this->attributes['slug'] = $slug."-".$slugNumber;
}
```

I only need this to happen the first time that the model is created, not when the model is updated. How can I skip the mutator when the model already exists and the slug is already good?

Answer (score -1):

```
this Delete your slug mutator and use the creating 
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Posts::saving(function(Posts $model){
            $random = mt_rand(10000, 99999);
            $model->slug = str_slug($model->title). '-'. $random;
        });
    }
```